# Use urlParams in mapStateToProps in react-router v6

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, react-hooks, react-router-dom

My mapStateToProps needs the component urlParams to select a portion of the redux store and I have tried using but I keep getting the error: "TypeError: ownProps.useParams is not a function"
[my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2KDuV.png)

Comment: `useParams` is a React hook so it won't be on the `props` object unless *some* parent component is passing a prop named `useParams. The `mapStateToProps` function doesn't look correct at all. Are you trying to pass a `collectionId` route match param value to the selector factory? Can you update your question to include a [minimal, complete, and reproducible code example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I'm understanding your question/code correctly, you are trying to use the `collectionId` route match param as a key into the `selectCollection` selector.

In `react-router-dom` v6 there are no longer route props so rendered components need to use the React hooks to access `navigate`, `location`, and `match`/`params`. You *could* go the route of creating a custom `withRouter` HOC to inject the match params as a prop, and be accessible for the `connect` HOC, but use of two Higher Order Components is completely unnecessary.

I propose using the hooks in the component.

```
import { useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import { useParams } from 'react-router-dom';

const CollectionPage = () => {
  const { collectionId } = useParams();
  const collection = useSelector(selectCollection(collectionId));

  return (
    ... JSX ...
  );
};

export default CollectionPage;
```

Comment: @SamuelBankole Sorry, I thought that part was clear, you don't need to use any HOCs now, default export the `CollectionPage` component as the `useSelector` hook handles subscribing to the store.

Comment: Thanks, @DrewReese, it worked. But why does the page open the developer tool and keep loading?  It opens the source and points here:
    export function useParams<Key extends string = string>(): Readonly<Params<Key>
> {
  let { matches } = React.useContext(RouteContext);
  let routeMatch = matches[matches.length - 1];
  return routeMatch ? (routeMatch.params as any) : {};
}

Comment: @SamuelBankole Dunno, is there an error message to go along with that?

Comment: No error message. It works fine when I close the developer tools but the selector is not received until I close the developer tools

Comment: Do we still benefit form the 'reselect' library by doing it this way?

Comment: @Hermeneutiker Yes, if selector is [correctly created to take an argument](https://github.com/reduxjs/reselect#q-how-do-i-create-a-selector-that-takes-an-argument) then I believe so.